# Can not use variable from other namespace as default function parameter in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5, in one class I define the function:

```
<?php namespace App\Helpers;

use App\Helpers\CommonConst;

class ResTools {

    public static function resErr($data, $statusCode=CommonConst::$ERROR_CODES['BAD_REQUEST']){
        // Some code here
    }
}
```

And the CommonConst is:

```
class CommonConst {
    public static $ERROR_CODES = [
        'OK' => 200,
        'BAD_REQUEST' => 400,
        'UNAUTHORIZED' => 401,
        'FORBIDEN' => 403,
        'NOT_FOUND' => 404,
        'METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED' => 405,
        'INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR' => 500,
    ];


}
```

When running I always got the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '$ERROR_CODES' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, your `$ERROR_CODES` variable is not a constant, it's a static variable. You cannot default the values of your method parameters to variables.

Here's an example:

http://ideone.com/Hog5cD